# How to generate laravel-migrations from an edited model?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I've been looking into PHP-frameworks lately to find out which suits me best. I've had some experience with the java Play! framework which did some very nice things. One very nice feature that I haven't found in Laravel yet, is that when you edit your model, it can generate migrations for you. Is there a way in Laravel to generate migrations automatically from edits on your model? This would seem like a huge improvement to me, since migrations seem like a bit of a hassle to me right now.

I'm looking forward to your opinions and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only specify the columns in the migration and not on the model, so you don't have to edit anything on the model.

You first specify the columns (properties) for a table in the [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations).
Then you use those properties in your [Eloquent Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#eloquent-models).

You don't have to put all properties in the model, when you create a column with a migration it is accessable via a model, without also specifying it in the model.

Comment: But that's not automatically updated on the model in Laravel right? So whenever you want to edit your model you also have to write a migration. You have to specify your new model properties in your model and in your migration, which seems redundant.

Comment: You only write the properties in the migration.